# What were the German "general" ranks in World War II?

Tags: world-war-two, military, nazi-germany

The Anglo-American armies share ranks up to "full" (or four star) general. (The German army has ranks equivalent to those armies for non-general officers). The American army deviated from the English pattern with a five star "General of the Army." This rank was created after the Civil War, first award to Grant and then Sherman, enabling them to outrank four star General Robert E. Lee. A "super five" star rank, General of the Armies, was created as a result of World War I for General Pershing who outranked Grant and Sherman (and later five star generals). In 1976, a BiCentennial Congress retroactively awarded George Washington "super five" star rank with effect before Pershing's, making him the most senior U.S. general.

What were German World War II ranks? Is Major General a division commmander, Leutnant General the equivalent of an Anglo-American Lieutenant General? What level is Colonel General? Where would Field Marshal fit on the four or five star continuum? Is there any rank higher than Field Marshal? And is it true the Germany (not just Hitler) never appointed any more Field Marshals after Paulus surrendered at Stalingrad?

Comment: Douglas MacArthur and a few other military leaders were also granted (exceptional) [five-star rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-star_rank) in the U.S. army during WW II. My understanding is that this was meant to help them in projecting American power in allies that included e.g. Soviet Marshalls.

Comment: @Drux: MacArthur (and Eisenhower) were among the "later" five star generals (than Grant and Sherman).

Comment: yes, of course, them being WW II generals. I wonder if there are any "banana republics" that have "seven-star generals", or similar ("[Generalississimi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalissimo)", say), in their local armies :)

Comment: @Drux: I would call an American "super five" "General of the Armies a "six star general."

Comment: Well, you might, but it [looks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Douglas_MacArthur_promotion_order_to_General_of_the_Armies.jpg) as if Douglas MacArthur did not even get a raise (out of what e.g. Wikipedia still considers a promotion to [five-star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six-star_rank) rank :)

Comment: @Drux - our generals go upto 11

Comment: @mgb how comes 11 and not [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)?

Comment: @Drux http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven

Comment: @Drux: I think this means 11 levels of OFFICERS (six officers up to colonel, five levels of general).

Comment: @TomAu -- I see, so not 11-star generals (was not familiar with the idiom :)

Comment: @Drux: A five star general would be O-11, where "O" stands for officer.

Comment: @Tom Au - Grant and Sherman were not promoted to outrank Lee (who after all was never legally higher than a colonel) but to reward them for defeating the Rebellion.  Grant and Sheridan (1888) used four stars, Sherman used two stars and a US eagle as insignia, and they are usually counted as four star, not five star, generals.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_officers_in_the_United_States

Comment: Slight nitpick: General of the Army in the US Army is equivalent to a UK and Commonwealth Field Marshal; ie, they’re both five-star ranks, and both have the NATO officer code of OF-10. Field Marshal isn’t an operative rank though in the British army, as aren’t the Royal Navy and RAF equivalents, and the last General of the Army (Omar Bradley) died in 1981. Both still formally exist though

Comment: Also; in respect to the ‘super five star’ (it’s actually off the NATO scale, but adjacent) not only did Germany have its own equivalent of that, with the six-star ‘Reichsmarschall’ rank held by Göring, so did the Italian Army, with its ‘Marshal of the Empire’ rank held by Mussolini and King Victor Emmanuele III.

Comment: Also it isn’t the case that the US Army “deviated from the English (sic) pattern”: the rank of General of the Army was instituted during WW2 (as was Pershing’s rank during WW1) for the exact reason that the British Army, and other allied armies, had 5-star ranks (in the British Army; Field Marshal), and the US Army did not. It’s speculated that the reason that the reason ‘Field Marshal’ wasn’t used for this rank is because that would have meant one of the, Marshall, would have ended up becoming ‘Field Marshal Marshall’. The name of the rank thus alluded to the ones held by Pershing and Grant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This wasn't a hard google search :)

On this topic the [wikipedia page of WW2 German Army ranks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_German_Army_ranks_and_insignia) serves with lot of data, with many related links.

I hope it serves the information you are looking for.

Comment: Wikipedia [elsewhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six-star_rank) also says that "the Institute of Heraldry produced a single sketch of how the insignia for a six-star rank would appear; this sketch was later filed in Douglas MacArthur's service record". I'd be curious if anybody has seen this service-record-plus-sketch (available online).

Comment: @Drux hmm I am not an expert heraldist, but isn't german and american star counting going on a different platform? I saw only three stars at max. I have the impression they can't be compared this way.

Comment: Where (for which country) did you see three stars at max? American four-star generals (e.g. [Colin Powell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Powell)) are frequently mentioned in the news.

Comment: @Drux you are right about US stars, I counted the german side, the feldmarsall has some X shaped insignia instead of increasing star numbers, that's what I meant.

Comment: I see. My comment and additional question re Douglas MacArthur was in a U.S-context and to people in general.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, Goering held the unique rank of "Reichsmarshall" which outranked a plain old Field Marshal (Generalfeldmarschall) and would be equivalent to a six star US general were such a rank to currently exist. This was part of Hitler's nomination of Goering as his designated successor. Goering was of course subordinate to Hitler who was, as German head of state, commander in chief of all German forces (but that is of course usually a position not a rank as such).

Answer (score 0):

For WWII at least, from bottom up, a *Generalmajor* wore an insignia without stars, a *Generalleutnant* wore an insignia with one star, a *General* (of Infantry, Cavalry, etc.) wore an insignia with two stars, a *Generaloberst* (literally, colonel-general) wore an insignia with three stars, and a *Generalfeldmarschall* wore an insignia with two diagonally crossed marshal batons. So their insignia had one star less than their American equivalents, the names of the ranks were not exact translantions of the American ones, and there were only four ranks, including that of Marshal.

Answer (score -1):

Nope, there were seven more appointed after Paulus:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_German_Field_Marshals

Comment: You are counting the number of promotions after Paulus' promotion, which is not the same as the number of promotions after his surrender at Stalingrad. A few significant days lie in between. It looks as if they make the requested list smaller, but not empty. It turns out that Robert Ritter von Greim (whom I've never heard about so far) accepted his just 5 days before his promoter's suicide: quite a promotion.